# ASP.NET Core Web API : how to register different appsettings.json files in api and business logic projects

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have two projects, Web API and business logic (will call it BL for short). The Web API is dependent on the `BL` project. In both I have different `appsettings.json`. I am not sure how to do registration of different appsettings for these two different projects.

In the Web API's `Program.cs`, I have service registration for configuration that looks like this:

```
var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
   .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", false)
   .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
   .Build();

builder.Services.ConfigureServices(configBuilder);

builder.Services.AddOptions<ApiAppSettingsOptions>()
    .Bind(config.GetSection("ApiAppSettings"));
builder.Services.AddOptions<BlAppSettingsOptions>()
    .Bind(config.GetSection("BlAppSettings"));
```

After this if I use `BlAppSettings` in the `BL` project

```
public SomeBlService(IOptions<BlAppSettingsOptions> configOptions)
{
    var config = configOptions.Value;   // this returns the BlAppSettingsOptions class with all properties null
}
```

so the config I get has all properties null.

I know why this happens, it's because I never registered `appsettings.json` that has the `BlAppSettings`, but the problem is I don't know how. if I just do something like

```
public static IConfiguration SetupConfiguration()
{
    return new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile($"api-appsettings.json", false)
        .AddJsonFile($"bl-appsettings.json", false)
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .Build();
}
```

then I have to place the `bl-appsettings.json` in the API project, if I don't then I have to specify full path, both solutions sounds spaghetti, is the any other way?

Comment: Maybe I'm not aware of some standard for this, but in the entirety of my .Net experience config files have always been attached to the deployable application instance.  Not to each individual class library of a solution.  When specific class libraries had specific configuration needs, their source could include a *sample* configuration file.  And any application which wants to use that class library would need to ensure its deployed configuration has the necessary settings.  But a config file actually bundled with a class library sounds very strange to me...

Comment: @David Oh thats something new I didn't know. I've worked on some older projects and those has web.config files in each project, I thought we.config had the same purpose as appsettings.json

Comment: It does, at least as far as I've used them, but the same has been true for web.config files.  I've sometimes seen build-/deploy-time custom scripts/tools which would in some way merge configurations from known locations, but that's always been very custom and not a generic tool for the task.  I'm certainly curious to see if anybody has a better answer in the direction you're looking for, but in my experience any time this was desired it was abandoned quickly because it's just easier to reason about configs at the deployable-artifact level instead.

Comment: @David hmm yeah that makes sense, wonder if there is a better solution, but I guess writing all configs in the API proejct would work alright :)

Comment: Or you might use cloud service to put your configuration settings?